# Ember-Simple-Auth 3.1 using Ember-Simple-Auth-Devise.js Callback

Tags: authentication, ember.js

I'm using Ember-Simple-Auth on an Ember-CLI project, and I'm also using the provided ember-simple-auth-devise authenticator that comes with 3.1. I'm able to login and logout successful, but I can't figure out where's the best place to put the callback (or when the promise resolves) upon successfully logging in. I want to be able to use the data returned by my API on my app after logging in. Any suggestions and advice would be highly appreciated! If requested, I can also provide code samples (although I figured it wasn't necessary since what I have implemented thus far is nothing custom).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the session is authenticated successfully, the `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` action is triggered (see http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#Ember-SimpleAuth-ApplicationRouteMixin-sessionAuthenticationSucceeded, there are also more actions for other events). So that's a good place to react to the session becoming authenticated.

As the authenticator will set all values the server responds with as properties on the session you could also define additional properties that depend on these - see example here (where the `account` property depends on the `accountId` property that's read from the server response): https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/4-authenticated-account.html#L101

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I didn't know that the authenticator sets all the values returned from the server to the session. If I wanted to manually get a hold of a property returned, would this be the best way to do inside the `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` method: `this.get('session.store').get('_lastData').some_property` ?

Comment: No, you just do `this.get('session.some_property')`